# How to change the site title

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to change the site name when I search it on google. the only thing that appear is "React App" and i dont know how change it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMB5C.png)

I tryed change the

`<title>Ton Redutores</title>`

in index.html but it just change the guide name

Answer (score 1):

See the first-party Google article, [Influencing your title links in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/title-link). A snippet from the article:

> [image]
>
> Google Search uses the following sources to automatically determine title links:
>
> - Content in `<title>` elements
> - Main visual title shown on the page
> - Heading elements, such as `<h1>` elements
> - Other content that's large and prominent through the use of style treatments
> - Other text contained in the page
> - Anchor text on the page
> - Text within links that point to the page

Specific to your `create-react-app` project: be sure to edit the actual `<title></title>` element text to include the desired title (e.g. `Ton Redutores`) in the file `public/index.html` in your project repository (see [folder structure](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/)), then re-build and re-publish your site, and keep in mind that search result updates are not instantaneous: it takes time to re-index your site.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you might need to change/add the `<title>` Your Title `</title>` to the index.html file in the `public` folder.

Keep in mind it has to be located between the `<head>`...`</head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<title>` tag is in the `<head>` tag. Then, you just need to be patient.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Ton Redutores</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </body>
</HTML>
```